# Rspec: Testing to make sure email is not sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am running a test to make sure emails are not sent to certain users:

```
it "does not send reminders to users who are not subscribed" do
        expect(ReminderMailer).not_to receive(:send_reminder).with("whatever", user.id).and_return(double(deliver_now: true))
        book.send_reminders("whatever", user.id)
      end
```

Book.rb

```
def send_reminders(medium, user_id)
    ReminderMailer.send_reminder(medium, user_id).deliver_now
end
```

But the current test is saying:

> and_return is not supported with negative message expectations

If I remove the and_return portion:

```
it "does not send reminders to users who are not subscribed" do
        expect(ReminderMailer).not_to receive(:send_reminder).with("whatever", user.id)
        book.send_reminders("whatever")
      end
```

Then the test fails because:

> undefined method `deliver_now' for nil:NilClass

How can I test that an action mailer method with specific parameters are *not* called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some problems with your code:

1. The number of arguments passed to method `send_reminders` seems wrong (you pass only 1 argument 'whatever' but no user id)
2. I don't see any condition to filter user, is it in `ReminderMailer`'s method `send_reminder`? So it will call `send_reminder` anyway, just won't send mail, right? It's not what you expected.

If so, you could try this:

```
expect {
  book.send_reminders("whatever")
}.not_to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count)
```

It will expect no mail was actually sent. Good luck bro!

Comment: thanks man! Woops, I simplified the code and missed one of the arguments, thanks for the answer

Comment: Oops..        getting "change` requires either an object and message (`change(obj, :msg)`) or a block (`change { }`). You passed an object but no message."